# How to Choose if a reaction will go elimination of substitution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I want to know how to choose if a given reaction will prefer going substitution mechanism or elimination mechanism.Both elimination and substitution reactions have types like Sn1 ,Sn2 ,SnNGP,Sni and E1 ,E2 ,E1CB

I know how to decide (if given that reaction is substitution reaction or elimination reactiin) which type among these a given reaction will go but I am always confused on choosing that the reaction will be substitution or elimination.

Any help/contribution appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It mainly depends on the reagent. If the attacking reagent has more nucleophilic character ie. tendency to act as a nucleophile, Substitution reactions will be preferred. On the other hand, if the reagent has more tendency to act as a base, elimination reactions will occur. In cases where a reagent falls under both categories, you can go into additional details like whether the compound has a Beta-Hydrogen to eliminate, leaving group tendencies etc.